# How do I log out of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I cannot find any button anywhere to log out.

I've searched and apparently no one has ever asked how to log out.

Comment: Click Stack Exchange logo in the top right, log out is in the dropdown.

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*